# Haskell - Parsing specific patterns from a string

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to solve a problem to do with parsing patterns from a string in Haskell.

Given the following string:

```
s = "/show\ hello how are /dont\ you /;dont\ doing /;show\"
```

The program would read until finding '/' then hold content found until finding '\'. The content will be compared against a list of approved words which I have already sorted.

The issue I'm having is actually parsing the content from the string and holding on to it to perform the required checks.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Strings are lists, so use the list functions in prelude, such as `takeWhile`  to tackle the problem one step at a time, then combine the steps until you get the solution. Or, you look into Parsec.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat. Here's a hint for a particularly quick and dirty way:

```
Text.Regex.TDFA> let s = "/show\\ hellow how are /dont\\ you /;dont\\ doing /;show\\"
Text.Regex.TDFA> s =~ "/[^/\\]*\\\\" :: [[String]]
[["/show\\"],["/dont\\"],["/;dont\\"],["/;show\\"]]
```